# In IE "background-attachment:fixed" screws up my background-size when zoomed

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming, fixed, background-attachment

I want all of my containers to be full screen size and the background to completely fill it without repeating or scrolling. So of course I use "background-size: cover;" and "background-attachment:fixed;" and this works perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome. For IE 8 I use a JavaScript plug-in.

When I opened my page in IE 11 it seemed to work fine as well as long as I didn't zoom. If I zoom out in IE the background gets smaller too. This doesn't happen without "background-attachment:fixed". Only in this combination it zooms my background which I really don't want.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much.

Here my full code:

```
#someContainer{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   
background: url(backgrounds/main.jpg) top center;
background-attachment:fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
-moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
-o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/
-ms-behavior: url(polyfill/backgroundsize.min.htc);
behavior: url(polyfill/backgroundsize.min.htc)
}
```